# Elasticsearch scroll api search "from"

Tags: php, xml, elasticsearch

I have a script that generates sitemaps based on url index `http://example.com/sitemap.index.xml` where `index` is a number `>0` that defines what results should be included in each chunk.

```
$chunk = 10000;
$counter = 0;

$scroll = $es->search(array(
    "index" => "index",
    "type" => "type",
    "scroll" => "1m",
    "search_type" => "scan",
    "size" => 10,
    "from" => $chunk * ($index - 1)
));
$sid = $scroll['_scroll_id'];

while($counter < $chunk){
    $docs = $es->scroll(array(
        "scroll_id" => $sid,
        "scroll" => "1m"
    ));
    $sid = $docs['_scroll_id'];
    $counter += count($docs['hits']['hits']);
}

// ...
```

Now each time I access `http://example.com/sitemap.1.xml` or `http://example.com/sitemap.2.xml` the results returned from ES are exactly the same. It returns `50` results (10 per each shard) but does not seem to take count of `from = 0`, `from = 10000`.

I'm using `elasticsearch-php` as ES library.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that, for every iteration results retruned are same?

Comment: @Shastry, yes, the results are exactly the same no matter what `from = ?` I pass to the initial `search()` request.

Comment: I have used Scan and Scroll in Java. But i didnt get into this type of situation. Can i provide you the java code?

Comment: @Shastry, sure ... you can make a gist and pass me the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: I will provide it as an answer. Take a look at it

Comment: scan disables sorting so don't think the from field even makes sense although i'm unable to answer why it doesn't throw and error or the document doesn't explicitly specify it ..Probably you need to try just search and scroll and not use scan. Here there is more info http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html#search-request-scroll

Answer (score -1):

In Java, it can be done as follows

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
SearchResponse scrollResp = Constants.client.prepareSearch(index)
        .setTypes(type).setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).setQuery(query)
        .setSize(500).execute().actionGet();
while (true) {
    scrollResp = Constants.client
            .prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();
    System.out.println("Record count :"
            + scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length);
    total = total + scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length;
    System.out.println("Total record count: " + total);
    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits()) {
    //handle the hit
    }
    // Break condition: No hits are returned
    if (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length == 0) {
        System.out.println("All records are fetched");
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't see `setFrom(?)` in your search query. Your example is good for returning all records for specific `_type` but not a specific chunk from it. As my original question says, I'm building a sitemap so I off course have a limit of document size and url's count, therefore I need to split all my sitemaps into smaller ones `sitemap.1.xml`, `sitemap.2.xml`. So every request to `url/sitemap.1.xml` will return the first `10000` hits, for `url/sitemap.2.xml` it would return hits between `10001` and `20000`.